# Get text with inner tags as string in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using css selector to extract a text inside a paragraph, for example: `'<p>abc<br>xyz<br></p>'`

```
content = txt.css('p::text').get()
```

returns

```
abcxyz
```

but I want

```
abc<br>xyz<br>
```

Comment: Use `txt.css('p').get()` to get the outer tags and all its content. You also get `<p>` and `</p>`, though.

Answer (score 0):

`get()` only returns first found text

you need to use `getall()` and it will return a list and then you need to join it

```
" "join(txt.css('p *::text').getall())
```